# Displaying black transparent layer instead of alert

Tags: android

I have developed an app where i am using Async task with in the async task after performing some operation in onPostExecute() method i am displaying an alert. Every thing is working fine but the problem is when application is coming from background instead of displaying a alert it is showing the black transparent layer. why it is happening?? Any ideas??

Here is my code snippet and steps to reproduce the issue:

Please create an activity to use async task:

```
private class ImageUploaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    private void showLoading()
    {
        mProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(myActivity.this,
                "Loading", "Please wait...", false, false);
    }
    private void dismissLoading()
    {
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        showLoading();



    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try
        {
        Thread.sleep(50000);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
         dismissLoading();
         showAlert(myActivity.this,"Info","Process Finished.");

    }
    public  void showAlert(Context context, String Title, String Message) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertbox.setTitle(Title);
        alertbox.setMessage(Message);
        alertbox.setCancelable(false);
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
        alertbox.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
         dismissLoading();
    }
}
```

Steps to Reproduce the Issue:

1)start the Async task and send the app to background

2) Make sure that Async task is completed and bring the app to foreground

3) Instead of the Alert it will show black tranparent screen.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try implement onResume() from Activity lifecycle and problem will be solved ;-)
It could check whether the asyncTask has completed and get screen, and show alert properly...